# how to make navbar responsive and collapseable

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this navbar to be reponsive, im not too familiar with reponsive layouts but i know how to use media queries a little bit, and i haven't tried anything yet since i don't know where to start. How can i get this navbar to shrink with the screen size and at a certain breakpoint, collapse into a 3 lined button.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px gray;
  align-items: center;
  height: 7vh;
}

.navbar .logo {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 3em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .right-links {
  display: flex;
  gap: .2em;
  padding-inline-end: 12em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 15vw;
}

.navbar .left-links {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding-inline-start: 12rem;
}

.navbar .right-links .loginbtn {
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 3em;
  width: 5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.navbar .right-links .loginbtn:hover {
  background: rgb(47, 58, 178, 0.1);
  color: rgb(47, 58, 178);
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar .right-links .signupbtn {
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: rgb(59, 73, 223);
  border-color: rgb(59, 73, 223);
  border-style: solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.navbar .right-links .signupbtn:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgb(47, 58, 178);
  border: rgb(47, 58, 178);
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar .left-links .search-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.navbar .left-links .search-box input {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  width: 400px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.navbar .left-links .search-box button {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.navbar .left-links .search-box button:hover {
  background: rgb(47, 58, 178, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="left-links">
    <img href="/" class="logo" src="/imgs/dev.to.webp" alt="" />
    <div class="search-box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
      <button class="search-bottom">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="crayons-icon c-btn__icon" focusable="false"><path d="m18.031 16.617 4.283 4.282-1.415 1.415-4.282-4.283A8.96 8.96 0 0 1 11 20c-4.968 0-9-4.032-9-9s4.032-9 9-9 9 4.032 9 9a8.96 8.96 0 0 1-1.969 5.617zm-2.006-.742A6.977 6.977 0 0 0 18 11c0-3.868-3.133-7-7-7-3.868 0-7 3.132-7 7 0 3.867 3.132 7 7 7a6.977 6.977 0 0 0 4.875-1.975l.15-.15z"></path></svg>
          </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-links">
    <button class="loginBtn">Log In</button>
    <button class="signupBtn">Create account</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using relative units, the view will be able to easily adapt to the state of the screen. And setting a breakpoint we can set a styling element based on the viewport. So that way the content that we display on the page can be adjusted to various roles, be it layout or font size.

```
html, body {    
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}   
.container {    
display: flex;    
flex-wrap: wrap; 
}   
.box {    
min-height: 150px;   
width: 100%; 
}   /*For small screens*/
@media screen and
(min-width: 450px) {    
.light_blue, 
.green {
 width: 50%    
} 
}   /*For medium-sized device screens*/ 
@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {    
.red {
width: 33%;    
}
.orange {
width: 67%;    
} 
}   /*For large screens*/ 
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {    
  .container {
 width: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;    
} 
}
```

when in a large viewport size, the content box has margins on the left and right, this is because we set the .container to apply margin-left and margin-left with an auto value if the min-width is 800.

Comment: Where are you getting those css-classes from? This doesnt seem to answer the question